# PresentationFramework.pdb не загружен. При запуске проекта происходит дозагрузка, как убрать?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Непонятно какое моё действие привело к этому, это происходит в любом проекте, который был создан ранее или новом

Comment: [Настройка расположения файлов символов и параметров загрузки](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#configure-location-of-symbol-files-and-loading-options) - очистите там всё.